# Expo ImagePicker crashed on IOS Gallery not opening

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, imagepicker

**When I try to use expo imagepicker, the application freezes, opens the gallery or the camera and they close immediately, this only happens to me on iOS, on Android it works perfectly.**

**This is my code**

```
  getPermissionAsync = async () => {
    if (Constants.platform.ios) {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA, Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      if (status !== "granted") {
        alert(
          "Lo sentimos, necesitamos permisos de cámara para hacer que esto funcione!"
        );
      }
    }
  };

  _pickImage = async type => {
    let result = null;
    if (type == "galeria") {
      result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        quality: 0.5,
        base64: true
      });
    } else {
      result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        quality: 0.5,
        base64: true
      });
    }

    if (result != null && !result.cancelled) {
      let arr = this.state.imagenesAdjuntas;
      arr.push(result);
      this.setState({ imagenesAdjuntas: arr });
    }
  };
```

**These are the dependencies**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "expo": "^33.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "^6.0.0",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-blur": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-constants": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-font": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^5.0.1",
    "expo-mail-composer": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "~5.0.1",
    "firebase": "^7.2.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animated-hide-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-banner-carousel": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.6",
    "react-native-flip-card": "^3.5.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.2.1",
    "react-native-maps": "~0.24.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.1.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-smtp-mailer": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
    "sharp": "^0.22.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.1.1"
  },
```

**This is the app.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "App Name",
    "slug": "appname",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "33.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "loading": {
      "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
      "hideExponentText": false
    },
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#0088AD"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "packagerOpts": {
      "assetExts": [
        "ttf",
        "mp4",
        "otf",
        "xml",
        "html",
        "js"
      ]
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.company.name"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.company.name",
      "config": {
      }
    },
    "description": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try this example based on newer sdk: https://snack.expo.io/@samyoptimize/playful-raspberrie

Answer (score 2):

try adding this to your object, like so,

```
ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
     mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
     quality: 0.5,
     base64: true
     presentationStyle: 0 //add this
});
```

with this everything should be perfectly working on IOS

Answer (score 1):

You should add this permission in project plist file inside xcode.
Add these two entry in file

```
NSCameraUsageDescription



NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
```

That would help you, its help me